# How to link existing parse user to facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

Already done with facebook login? but I don't know a link to Parse user.

> Even though, the user already existed it is creating a separate account.
>   Suggestion are welcome?

Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground()`](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers-link) to link an existing user with Facebook.

I highly recommend that you take a look at the [Android SDK docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers), as they are very well written.

Comment: I ddon't what is permission part from it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. Maybe try using some form of translator if English is not your primary language?

Comment: I don't know what is permission part in the following code      ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback());

Comment: It is simply an array of strings that specify what data you want the Facebook user to give to you. [Here's facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference)

Comment: newer link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference